# How to make Extjs 4.2 bar chart with 'pagination'

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, pagination

I have over 100 items (it is loaded dimamicly so it might be more in the feature) in jsonStore and want to display them using chart. Unfortunately render all features at one time will make chart unreadable. I want to display them in group of 20 items. 
How to add 'pagination' mechanism? Is there a possibility to add a limit and offset to data to be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It is enough to `paginate`locally / remotely the `store` attached to `chart`.

```js
Ext.require([
  'Ext.chart.*',
  'Ext.Window',
  'Ext.fx.target.Sprite',
  'Ext.layout.container.Fit',
  'Ext.window.MessageBox'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {

  window.generateData = function(n, floor) {
    var data = [],
      p = (Math.random() * 11) + 1,
      i;

    floor = (!floor && floor !== 0) ? 20 : floor;

    for (i = 0; i < (n || 12); i++) {
      data.push({
        name: Ext.Date.monthNames[i % 12],
        data1: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor)),
        data2: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor)),
        data3: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor)),
        data4: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor)),
        data5: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor)),
        data6: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor)),
        data7: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor)),
        data8: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor)),
        data9: Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * 100), floor))
      });
    }
    return data;
  };


  window.store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7', 'data9', 'data9'],
    data: generateData(),
    pageSize: 3,
    page: 0
  });

  window.doFilter = function() {
    var k = 0,
      start = store1.page * store1.pageSize;

    store1.clearFilter();
     if(start<0) start = 0;// add the max page test :P

    store1.filter(function(r) {
      return k++ >= start && k <= start + store1.pageSize;
    });
  }
  doFilter();
  var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    style: 'background:#fff',
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    store: store1,
    axes: [{
      type: 'Numeric',
      position: 'left',
      fields: ['data1'],
      label: {
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
      },
      title: 'Number of Hits',
      grid: true,
      minimum: 0
    }, {
      type: 'Category',
      position: 'bottom',
      fields: ['name'],
      title: 'Month of the Year'
    }],
    series: [{
      type: 'column',
      axis: 'left',
      highlight: true,
      tips: {
        trackMouse: true,
        renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
          this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + ' $');
        }
      },
      label: {
        display: 'insideEnd',
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        field: 'data1',
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
        orientation: 'vertical',
        color: '#333'
      },
      xField: 'name',
      yField: 'data1'
    }]
  });


  var win = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
     renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    minHeight: 300,
    minWidth: 550,
    hidden: false,
    maximizable: true,
    title: 'Column Chart',
    autoShow: true,
    layout: 'fit',

    items: chart,
    tbar: [{
      text: 'Prev',
      handler: function() {
        store1.page--;
        doFilter();
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Next',
      handler: function() {
        store1.page++;
        doFilter();
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-debug-w-comments.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```